# How to use sourcemaps to restore the original file?

Tags: javascript, source-maps

I have a file that has been transpiled from ES6 to ES5 using Babel. I have sourcemap. I am assuming I can restore the original file (the way it looked when written in ES6) using these resources.

How is it done?

Is there a CLI tool to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Open up the source map in a text editor, and you’ll see that it’s mostly just a simple JSON object. The “sources” field contains an array of URLs/paths to all source files, which can help you to find them. There is also an optional “sourcesContent” field, which also is an array, where each item contains the *contents* of the file at the same index in the “sources” array; if so, you could find the original code right in the source map.

A CLI tool? Well, there’s [source-map-visualize](https://github.com/lydell/source-map-visualize) which tries to find all original sources and pre-loads them into this [online source map visualization](https://github.com/sokra/source-map-visualization).

Comment: I think the most basic way is to use Mozilla `source-map` package, https://github.com/mozilla/source-map/#consuming-a-source-map, e.g. `sourcemap.SourceMapConsumer(map).sourcesContent[0]`. Consider adding that to your answer .

Comment: @GajusKuizinas there is absolutely no need to use the `source-map` package for this task. `JSON.parse(map).sourcesContent[0]` would do the same thing.

Comment: Did not realise that. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

There's a nice web service to do that: http://sokra.github.io/source-map-visualization/

- Click on "Custom"
- Select your `*.js` file
- Select the corresponding `*.js.map` file
- Browse the non-minified code on the right

There might be a lot of noise from `webpack:///node_modules/` modules that you're probably not interested in. You can try to find the I found that simply searching for `webpack:///src` usually brings up the *actual* source code within the whole snippet.

Answer (score 5):

Very simple NodeJS implementation which I wrote for my needs.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { SourceMapConsumer } = require("source-map");

fs.readFile('./example.js', 'utf8' , (err, data) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);

  const sourceMapData = data.split('//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,')[1];
  let buff = new Buffer.from(sourceMapData, 'base64');
  let rawSourceMap = buff.toString('ascii');

  const parsed = SourceMapConsumer(rawSourceMap);

  fs.writeFile('example.ts', parsed.sourcesContent, function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i wrote a script as well that came handy to me. I'll share it here it might come handy to someone
this script assumes that the `.map.(js|css)` has a structure like

```json
{
    "version": 3,
    "file": "static/js/15.80b7f5e4.chunk.js",
    "mappings": "iOAkCA,UAzBqB",
    "sources": [
        "path/to/afile.js"
    ],
    "sourcesContent": [
        "content of the file"
    ],
    "names": [
        "post",
        "useState"
    ],
    "sourceRoot": ""
}
```

thou i didn't make use of `names` and `mapping` entry on the map file i just mapped `sources` with `sourceContent` and recreated the file structure.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

function parseIfMap(filePath, content) {
  console.log("working on:", filePath);
  if (filePath.includes(".map")) {
    const jsonContent = JSON.parse(content);
    jsonContent.sources.forEach(function (value, index) {
      const parsed = path.parse(value);
      if (parsed.dir) {
        fs.mkdirSync(parsed.dir, { recursive: true });
      }
      fs.writeFile(
        value,
        jsonContent.sourcesContent[index],
        (path) => path && console.log(value, path)
      );
    });
  }
}

function readFiles(dirname, onError) {
  fs.readdir(dirname, function (err, filenames) {
    if (err) {
      onError(dirname, err);
      return;
    }
    filenames.forEach(function (filename) {
      const filePath = dirname + path.sep + filename;
      if (fs.lstatSync(filePath).isFile()) {
        fs.readFile(filePath, "utf-8", function (err, content) {
          if (err) {
            onError(err);
            return;
          }
          parseIfMap(filePath, content);
        });
      } else {
        readFiles(filePath, parseIfMap, onError);
      }
    });
  });
}
// change with you own file path
readFiles("static", console.log);
```

Comment: `working on: /root/app/service.js.map 

/root/index.js:15

        jsonContent.sourcesContent[index],

                                  ^` 

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') 
    at /root/index.js:15:35` 

`    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)` 

`    at parseIfMap (/root/index.js:8:25)` 

`    at /root/index.js:36:11

    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete]  

`(node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3)`